# What means this kind of expression with logics operators

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I have an boolean expression in javascript and i don't know what it means.

```
a = (b === LEFT && -2 || b === RIGHT && 2 || 0)
```

Please what does it mean ?

Comment: I have to understand it if i want to fix or maintain

Comment: Yikes. It’s a bad and unreliable way of writing `b === LEFT ? -2 : b === RIGHT ? 2 : 0` (and typically that would be on multiple lines). It’s not even shorter than that…

Comment: What is LEFT and RIGHT here?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt LEFT and RIGHT are constants

Comment: the expression has superfluous parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The && is a hacky shortcut if:

```
if (B === LEFT) {
    a = -2;
} else if (B === RIGHT) {
    a = 2;
} else {
    a = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one more shortcut with ternary operator

```
a = b === LEFT? -2: (b === RIGHT? 2 : 0)
```